# Cannot import tensorflow with no error popped out

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using a server with a Centos system.

Initially, I was using `tensorflow-gpu=1.14`.
I had to update it to a newer version.

So I created a new `conda` environment with python=3.7

I tried to `pip install tensorflow` but `ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.`  was shown.

So I found a solution `pip install wrapt --upgrade --ignore-installed` to fix the `wrapt` problem.

---

After that, I tried to import tensorflow in jupyter lab. but the cell ran forever and some information shown up in the `cmd` window.

```
[I 10:52:26.791 LabApp] Starting buffering for 93fcfc5c-c6f5-43b4-9756-38fdffb4e158:27aece01-3fde-4ef2-9118-1bd56b480fef
[I 10:52:34.407 LabApp] 302 GET / (192.168.1.143) 1.07ms
[I 10:52:36.157 LabApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 93fcfc5c-c6f5-43b4-9756-38fdffb4e158
[I 10:52:36.227 LabApp] Build is up to date
[I 10:52:42.123 LabApp] KernelRestarter: restarting kernel (1/5), keep random ports
kernel 93fcfc5c-c6f5-43b4-9756-38fdffb4e158 restarted
[I 10:52:44.805 LabApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 93fcfc5c-c6f5-43b4-9756-38fdffb4e158
[I 10:54:36.629 LabApp] Saving file at /Speech/Feature_engineering/PCA.ipynb
```

---

If I run `import tensorflow` in `cmd`

```
(tf24) [test@DL-200 ~]$ python
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 13:15:42) 
[GCC 7.2.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
Illegal instruction
```

---

Update

I have uninstalled `wrapt` and reinstalled `tensorflow` but the problem is not fixed.

Basically, I have removed the environment and restarted everything over but it did not work.

Comment: As soon as you throw something into the mix like your use of the `--ignore-installed` option to `pip`, you're opening yourself up to problems like this.  I'm guessing that you needed to use that option because you got some sort of version mismatch error otherwise, and it is that same version mismatch problem that is causing this crash.  I would suggest that you uninstall `wrapt` and any other modules that you have forced the install of, and figure out how to get all dependencies to install without errors or the need for override options like `--ignore-installed`.

Comment: This seems like a great place to use a virtualenv if you're not already doing so.  Doing that might resolve this problem.

Comment: @Steve I think I used virtual environment, didn't I? Isn't the conda environment a virtual?

Comment: Could be.  I don't know Conda at all.  That's why I added "if you're not already doing so".  If you are using a virtualenv, then I'd  suggest that you start over with a new env and not use any special options to `pip`, like `--ignore-installed`.  There's a reason you're having to add that option.  My concern is that whatever that reason is is the basis of your problem.  I could be totally wrong, of course, but I can't think of anything else for you to try.

Comment: Create new virtual environment using conda, `conda create --name tf python=3`, install tensorflow `!pip install tensorflow`. Thanks